# ps command: how show the complete command with options, pipes and redirection? (or all together)

Tags: ps, options

About the `ps` command, consider if for simplicity:

- in `tty3` is executed the `yes` command
- in `tty4` is executed the `yes > /dev/null` command

through `ps` I need to show in the report the complete command with *options, pipes and redirection*, in this case *redirection*, was tried `ps aux` and `ps -ef` and does not appear as expected, for both cases always appear `yes` - I need see `yes` **and** `yes > /dev/null`

```
... COMMAND
    yes
    yes > /dev/null
```

so currently the  `> /dev/null` part is not included. How accomplish this goal?

About a command with *pipe* it would be `mvn clean ... | tee ...` and about *option(s)* the command would be `tar -xzf  /path/to/filename.tar.gz`

```
... COMMAND
    mvn clean ... | tee ...
    tar -xzf  /path/to/filename.tar.gz
```

or all together: *options, pipes and redirection*

Comment: You can't, because those things aren't visible to `ps`. And e.g. in the case of a pipeline, there's multiple processes involved, so one-line-per-process output of `ps`  would need some changes. On Linux, it would be possible to look into `/proc/$pid/fd` to see where e.g. the stdin/stdout/stderr fds of a process are connected to, and I think it should be technically possible to use the information there to reconstruct pipelines too. Just don't know if there's an existing tool that can do that.

Comment: In Bash, you can do some trickery with DEBUG traps, but they get called once for each command, not for the whole pipeline at a time.

Comment: @ilkkachu interesting this situation, I thought was already available by `ps` or other command throughout these years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. At least, not without deconstructing output from `ps`, `lsof`, and a little bit of guesswork.

You can use `ps -ef` or maybe `ps -wwef` to get the command with its options, but redirections and pipes are not part of a command and so will not be shown